# Concatenate line feeds

Tags: sas, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate three string variables.

```
Data X ;
    a = "A" ;
    b = "B" ;
    c = "C" ;
    z = catx ( '0D0A'x, a, b, c ) ;
run;
```

I am trying to display the string values like this in the final dataset, so that the values appear one below the other -

**A**
**B**
**C**

But by using '0D0A'x option, the string appears as **ABC**. I have to display the **z** variable in an excel. If I had to output the same into a HTML file then I would have used "\n" as an option in CATX function. Is there a way where I can introduce new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted your example slightly:

```
libname test excel "%sysfunc(pathname(work))\text.xls";

Data test.X ;
    a = "A" ;
    b = "B" ;
    c = "C" ;
    z = catx ( '0D0A'x, a, b, c ) ;
run;

libname test clear;

x "explorer ""%sysfunc(pathname(work))\text.xls""";
```

If you use this approach, you get a value in cell D2 which contains the line breaks as expected. However, in order for them to display correctly, you have to enable the 'wrap text' option for the cell formatting.